# Cannot resolve method Facebook AccessToken

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

I have changed the Session to Access Token but it cannot resolve the method for getCurrentAccessToken and isOpened

```
// Fetch Facebook user info if the session is active
        AccessToken token = ParseFacebookUtils.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (token != null && token.isOpened()) {
            makeMeRequest();
        }
```

Old code was

```
   // Fetch Facebook user info if the session is active
        Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            makeMeRequest();
        }
    }
```

Finally I have edited this like below. And should be used in the place of getSession() for ParseFacebookUtils ?

```
 // Fetch Facebook user info if the session is active
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (token != null && token.isExpired()) {
           ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(token); makeMeRequest();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`, and check for the token expiry.

```
AccessToken token = ParseFacebookUtils.getController().getCurrentAccessToken();

if (token != null && !token.isExpired())
{
    // the user is logged-in with valid tocken
}
```

There will be one active `AccessToken` at a time, which can be set automatically by the `ParseFacebookUtils` library. So you just check the current token.

The only issue here is that `ParseFacebookUtils.getController()` is `private`, so just change it to `public` in the Utils class.

```
 public static FacebookController getController() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      if (controller == null) {
        controller = new FacebookController();
      }
      return controller;
    }
  }
```

Comment: So I need not use ParseFacebookUtils ? It imports users to Parse

Comment: @SagarAtalatti check here to see how to use `ParseFacebookUtils` https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseFacebookUtils-Android/tree/master/library/src/test/java/com/parse

Comment: Could you be specific on setting access token automatically with ParseFacebookUtils

Comment: @SagarAtalatti  check the answer now

Comment: Its shows getController has private access in com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils

Comment: I have been searching the whole what has Parse replaced getSession with because they don't use getSession anymore

Comment: @SagarAtalatti change `getController` from `private` to `public`